# Xamarin android binding library __AndroidNativeLibraries__.zip.new not found

Tags: android, xamarin, binding

I'm building a binding library which consists of a .jar file and an associated .so file.

The jar file is set with a build action of *embeddedjar*, while the .so file is set with a build action of *embeddednativelibrary*

The above is background to the error I'm getting when building the library.

I'm getting the error below:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Bindings.targets: Error: Error executing task CreateNativeLibraryArchive: /Users/jameslavery/Projects/DeviceAPI-Custom/DeviceAPI-Custom/obj/Debug/__AndroidNativeLibraries__.zip.new does not exist (DeviceAPI-Custom)

It appears that the intermediate file

__AndroidNativeLibraries.zip__.new

isn't being created.

Any thoughts/solution?

Comment: FYI, If you put a \ character in front of the first double underscore, it's going to show up correctly, not bolded as it normally does.

Comment: @hankide - thanks, thought there must be an escape for that!